# Nested Input Search in Table in Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a very simple problem that i can't fix it. I just need the autocomplete input in the table to function.

Pls see this stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-nested?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

```
onSelectProduct(val: string) {
    this.filteredOptions = this.form.get("products").valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(""),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    console.log(value);
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.options.filter(
      option => option.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? I don't know what is you want to do.

Comment: @bjdose. Just fix the autocomplete inside the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix the autocomplete you need to init the variable called `filteredOptions`.

Init that variable on the constructor. And take your value written into the input on the filter function.

```js
constructor() {
 // .. code omitted
 this.initFilteredOptionsByIndex(0);
}

initFilteredOptionsByIndex(index: number) {
  this.filteredOptions = this.form.get("products").valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(""),
    map(value => this._filter(value, index))
  );
}

onFocus(index: number) {
 // I use input focus to get each row index
 this.initFilteredOptionsByIndex(index);
}

private _filter(value: any, index: number): string[] {
  if (!value) {
    return [];
  }

  const filterValue = value[index].product_id.toLowerCase();

  return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
}
```

Solution available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-nested-gosxcf?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts).

Comment: This isnt working. Pls edit my stackblitz to see how it works

Comment: bjdose. I tried but its not working. Try to type something in the autocomplete and its not working. It doesnt autocomplete

Comment: I think you have problems with your browser or something similar because I click on the input and autocomplete show up. Try to check the console or using another browser.

Comment: Try to type the word "two" , it should only appear "two". There is "one" and "three" still appearing when you type "two"

Comment: You got it working in the first row. But on the succeeding rows it doesn't work cause you just did value[0].product_id. Its only accessing the first row.